# MLE for Linear Regression, student-t distributed error

Tags: regression, estimation, maximum-likelihood, linear, t-distribution

Say I have a $n$ pairs $(X_i, Y_i)$ and I have the relationship $$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i +\epsilon_i$$ where the error terms $\epsilon_i$ are iid from a student t-distribution with constant (known) degrees of freedom, (say $k\in\mathbb{N}$ degrees of freedom, where $k > 2$). If I wanted to compute the the MLE for $\beta_0, \beta_1$, how do I relate the given distribution to the parameters of interest?

Sorry if this is trivial, but I searched around and haven't really seen an example like this.

Comment: For implementation in R, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117980/regression-with-t-distributed-errors-and-massrlm and for more about the estimation, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120776/why-should-we-use-t-errors-instead-of-normal-errors/120787#120787 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236676/can-you-give-a-simple-intuitive-explanation-of-irls-method-to-find-the-mle-of-a/237384#237384

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The MLE is obtained by maximising the log-likelihood function, so the first thing you will want to do is have a look at this function.  Using the density function for the [Student T-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) with **known** degrees-of-freedom $k \in \mathbb{N}$, you can write the log-likelihood as:

$$\ell_\mathbf{x,y} (\beta_0, \beta_1) = - \sum_{i=1}^n \ln \Big( k + (y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 x_i)^2 \Big).$$

The residuals $r_i = y_i - \hat{\beta}_0 - \hat{\beta}_1 x_i$ under the MLE minimise $\sum_{i=1}^n \ln ( k + r_i^2 )$.  As $k \rightarrow \infty$ we have $\ln ( k + r_i^2 ) = \ln(k) + \ln(1+r_i^2/k) \approx \ln(k) + r_i^2/k$ so that the residuals minimise $\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^2$ in the limit, which is the standard OLS solutions for normally distributed errors.  Use of the T-distribution effectively dampens the effect of large residuals, through the above logarithmic transformation, and so the MLE is more tolerant of having some large residuals than in the normal case.

**Finding the MLE:** The MLE can be obtained via numerical maximisation of the log-likelihood using ordinary calculus techniques.  The gradient of the log-likelihood is given by the partial derivatives:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \ell_\mathbf{x,y}}{\partial \beta_0}(\beta_0, \beta_1) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2 (y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 x_i)}{k+(y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 x_i)^2}, \\[6pt]
\frac{\partial \ell_\mathbf{x,y}}{\partial \beta_1}(\beta_0, \beta_1) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2 x_i (y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 x_i)}{k+(y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1 x_i)^2}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This leads to the score equations:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
0 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2 (y_i - \hat{\beta}_0 - \hat{\beta}_1 x_i)}{k+(y_i - \hat{\beta}_0 - \hat{\beta}_1 x_i)^2}, \\[6pt]
0 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2 x_i (y_i - \hat{\beta}_0 - \hat{\beta}_1 x_i)}{k+(y_i - \hat{\beta}_0 - \hat{\beta}_1 x_i)^2}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

These equations can be solved numerically using iterative techniques such as Newton-Raphson or gradient-descent methods, or other more complicated methods.  The exact distribution of the MLE will be complicated, but for large samples the MLE should be normally distributed, according to standard large-sample theory.

Comment: Nice answer (+1), but you don't address some practical issues, such as potential non-uniqueness of solutions (there can be multiple local maxima in some situations; your score function approach should find *a* local maximum, and if you start it somewhere else it may find another; how should we make sure we at least find a fairly good one?). Here's a log-likelihood for an intercept-only model with $\nu>2$ on a small set of data https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffj5b.png

Comment: Agreed (+1) - I guess this is just a teaser, since a longer exposition of calculus and iterative numerical methods would be a much bigger answer.  (I don't really have a patience to give a longer answer!)  The best practical thing for an OP who is not solid on this optimisation would be to plot the log-likelihood as a surface plot over the two dimensions of the parameters over the range near some identified critical points; that way he can see if these are local or global, without having to be very sophisticated with theory.

Comment: Small correction, I think that as k goes to infinity we have that $ln(k+r_i^2)$ goes to $ln(k) + r_i^2/k$

Comment: @DrorSpeiser: Thanks --- edited.

Answer (score 0):

It seems  me that, in comparison to previous answer, easier result are available.

Infact if the $v$ parameter are known, the ML estimators for $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ mantain the usual OLS formulation. In other terms, the $\beta$s ML estimators under Student-t distribution for error terms are the same as in Normal case. However their variance are considerably inflated if $v$ is small.
Moreover usual t and F test remain valid.

See, Arnold Zellner: *Bayesian and Non-Bayesian Analysis of the Regression Model with Multivariate Student-t error terms  - Journal of the American Statistical Association, Vol. 71, No. 354 (Jun., 1976), pp.400-405*.